# Buying a new imac, which memory should i get?

Tags: imac, memory

For the new imacs that just came out, which memory upgrade should I get?

This:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820226095

or:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231428

The apple site shows that it's using 4GB 1333MHz DDR3 SDRAM - 2x2GB ram. Would the 1600 ram work as an upgrade or would it be incompatible? And what's the speed difference between the two, is it noticeable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Those are desktop DIMMs, you want the laptop DIMMs.
   Try [this search](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007609%20600006178%20600000401&IsNodeId=1&name=8GB%20%282%20x%204GB%29) instead. or [this search](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007968%20600032345%20600079017&IsNodeId=1&name=DDR3%201333%20%28PC3%2010600%29) which starts a the Mac search below.
2. 1600 would work, but it wouldn't be
   much faster as they would run at the lower frequency, but might have better latency.

Comment: Oh thanks, had no idea I needed the laptop version. Newegg even has a Mac memory section, maybe even more pertinent: http://www.newegg.com/Store/SubCategory.aspx?SubCategory=551&name=Mac-Memory

Comment: http://www.ramjet.com/ has good information on what their engineers have determined will work. They have a long history of pushing memory safely past what Apple officially recommends but still making it simple to find the right memory and not selling you something that won't work with your specific mac. Look for a guarantee or return process that speaks to what happens if you order the wrong memory. Sometimes better spec'ed ram works, sometimes is does not.

Comment: I have a pair of Mushkin Enhanced 2GB in my MBP and they work great, the 8GB version is $84 http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820226167